# Adaptador en android para reordenar por distancia

Tags: java, android, ordenamiento, adapter

Estoy tratando de reordenar mi lista de items por distancia (usando getListView de android, no uno personalizado) y estoy teniendo problemas.

Estoy obteniendo la distancia esférica en metros (tipo double) usando Maps Utils dentro del adaptador (SomeAdapter).

```
double distancia = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(fromCoord, toCoord);
```

Pero, después de que lleno el adaptador (AsyncTask), necesito recortarlo por distancia en onPostExecute y no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        try {
            SQLiteHelper dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(getActivity());
            pds = new SomeDataSource(dbHelper.db);

            ArrayList<Raids> some = pds.getAllRaids();

            SomeAdapter listViewAdapter = new SomeAdapter(getActivity(), some);
            getListView().setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

            SharedPreferences somename = context.getSharedPreferences("SomeName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Boolean UserOrder = somename.getBoolean("UserOrder", false);
            if (UserOrder){

            }

        } catch (SQLiteException | NullPointerException s) {
            Log.d("SomeName", "SomeFrag:", s);
        }
    }
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

implementa `Comparable` interface en tu `Raids` class -

```
class Raids implements Comparable<Raids> {
    private double distance;
...

@Override
public int compareTo(Raids instance2) {
    if (this.distance < instance2.distance)
        return -1;
    else if (this.distance > instance2.distance)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
  }
}
```

Luego llama a `Collections.sort` -

```
ArrayList<Raids> some = pds.getAllRaids();
Collections.sort(some);
```

y actualiza el adaptador-

```
listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```